# Category Manager Page in a Reload Loop Nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, category, nginx

When I go to the categories admin page the the page keeps loading over and over again.

I use NGINX on ubuntu 14.04.  How do I fix?

I checked the server log and each iframe reload get a 200.

[image]

It keeps on reloading a div in an iframe in an endless loop.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, the request hits magento and is not cached somewhere?

Comment: yes, first thing I checked. Cleared the browser cached and rm -rf * magento/var/cache. It' constantly reloads the page.  The access log returns a 200 status.  Strangest thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an NGINX configuration issue... {surprise, surprise}.

This config file work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a development environment. Don't forget to set the server_name and root variables for your environment.

NGINX.CONF

```
user              www-data;
worker_processes  1;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request "'
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    autoindex off;
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    keepalive_timeout  10;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/ja$

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

VHOST.CONFIG

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name YOURDOMAIN.com;  #<--- edit this
    rewrite / $scheme://dev.$host$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;  #<---edit this too.
    root /usr/share/nginx/magento;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Comment: so was it simply a missing server_name?

Comment: Please accept your own answer if your problem is resolved. This website is still in beta and we need a global answer rate of 80% http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into similar issue, except we have Magento setup in a subpath (/store). Every server{} has a root and server_name, every location has an alias(due to mandated directory structure.)

Turned out I didn't have the complete Nginx config setup for Magento specifically.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com *.domain.com domain.com domain.com.dev;
    access_log /var/www/domain.com/log/access-80.log;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/log/error-80.log;

    index index.htm index.html index.php;

    root /var/www/domain.com;

location / {
    root /var/www/domain.com/joomla;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include rewrites/php5.conf;
    }
}

location /store {
    alias /var/www/domain.com/magento;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /store/index.php;

    # Was missing this | START
    location ~ ^/store/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
    location /store/var/export/ { internal; }
    location ~ ^/store(.*).php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location  /store/. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    return 404;
    }
    # Was missing this | End
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include rewrites/php5.conf;
    }

}
}
```

The specific part of the missing code that affected everything in my environment was

```
location ~ ^/store(.*).php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

Which took me a minute to figure out since all sample code I find for that is purely with the store at root.

Answer (score 2):

For people who's problem didn't get fixed by the accepted answer.

```
location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

Adding this to a default nginx conf file did the trick for me!

Comment: I needed this for the /js/index.php/x.js requests to work on admin password reset pages. Thanks!