# Admin category page constantly reloading after fresh install (Magento 1.9.1)

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, nginx

After fresh install on server, categories admin page keeps loading over and over again. I use NGINX 1.8 on ubuntu 14.04.

[image: screen]

An additional symptom: catalog filters on front-end doesn't work too. I've tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41418/category-manager-page-in-a-reload-loop-nginx)  but it doesn't work.