# Category page manager stuck in reload (CentOS7 + ngingx 1.11.8)

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

I already checked out [Category Manager Page in a Reload Loop Nginx](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41418/category-manager-page-in-a-reload-loop-nginx) and saw a similar problem that I am encountering. The solutions mentioned in the mentioned topic **DO NOT** solve my problem. The Category page manager seems to be forever in a loop after trying to save a changed category. Unfortunately I use CentOS7 instead of Ubuntu and I think therefore my adjustments need to be different.

My nginx.conf

```
#user  nginx;
# The number of worker processes is changed automatically by CustomBuild, according to the number of CPU cores, if it's     set to "1"
worker_processes  4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
events {
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-events.conf;
}


http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
    default off;
    https on;
    }

    # For user configurations not maintained by DirectAdmin. Empty by default.
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-includes.conf;

    # Supplemental configuration
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-modsecurity-enable.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-gzip.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-proxy.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-ips.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-settings.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-vhosts.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-vhosts.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And my /conf.d/magento.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    # server_name magento.lan www.magento.lan; # like ServerName in Apache
    # root /var/www/magento; # document root, path to directory with files
    # index index.html index.php;
    autoindex off; # we don’t want users to see files in directories
    location ~ (^/(app/\|includes/\|lib/\|/pkginfo/\|var/\|report/config.xml)\|/\.svn/\|/\.git/\|/.hta.+) {
        deny all; #ensure sensitive files are not accessible
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # make index.php handle requests for /
        access_log off; # do not log access to static files
        expires max; # cache static files aggressively
    }

    location \~\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404; # if reference to php executable is invalid return 404
        expires off; # no need to cache php executable files
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on; # use persistent connects to backend
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default; # Store code is defined in 
    #administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {   ## This was apparently the solution due to others but not for me
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if one of the nginx/centos gurus can help me get rid of this annoying problem because I do not get it and my knowledge of nginx is too limited.

Let me know if any other files are needed.

---

More info: if the page is stuck in reload loop, then doing a browser refresh (F5 in chrome or CTRL-R in Firefox) unlocks the loop. Also doing the category edit on a mobile phone, doesn show this issue.

Weird or what ?

Comment: Like I said, I tried those solutions but they didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. So as I said this wasn't related to the previous mentioned topics.

This was related to Cloudflare's rocketscripting an js/css minify cache. It keeps the page in a loop after editting the category. After pressing F5 or CTRL-R it would then be okay. Disabling Cloudflare's rocketscripting and minify solved this.